# I created one transient model and wizard but not able to create a cron to clear data from transient model

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I try to find in schedule actions triggers in technical menu but it is not there...and also not able to create a new cron that can do the same.

Comment: Please add code of what you are trying to do. Transient model data is cleared regularly using a vacuum job by odoo itself. You don't need to do that.

Comment: @NinjaBat Actually the Cron which is responsible to clear data is not showing in my schedule triggers and also data is not cleared yet. I read one of the blog on odoo website it says we need to Turn on that cron and set time period to clean the data.

Comment: Not sure, why it doesn't show. It will be in the name of Base: Auto-vacuum internal data. Also check and update base module if still not found. 
addons/base/data/ir_cron_data.xml is the related file I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found that cron after upgrading base module.